# How to calculate interval between a group of dates?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, datetime

Every dates in the array represent a User interaction.
If there is a gap of > of 20 seconds between these dates I count a new User (lets call this group of dates a session).
Following my script I can count Users correctly.

- But I cannot calculate the average time for session.

Could you point me out what am I doing wrong, of any suggestion for a better code is very welcome. Thanks.

```
namespace test_code
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            DateTime[] dates = {
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,5),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,10), // 15 s USR 1 session

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,5,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,5,5),  // 05 s USR 2

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,1),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,2), // 03 s USR 3

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,1,0,0), 
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,2,0,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,2,0,20)  // 20 s USR 4
                            };


            int users = dates.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            int gapS = 20; // Gap between date in seconds
            double totalTimeGaps = 0;
            double totalTime = 0;

            for (int i = 0, n = i + 1; i < dates.Length - 1; i++, n++)
            {
                totalTime += (dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds;
                if ((dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds > gapS)
                {
                    users++;
                    totalTimeGaps += (dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds; // Does not count properly
                    Console.WriteLine(totalTimeGaps);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Users: " + users);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Time Avg. Session : " + (totalTime - totalTimeGaps)/users);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Last version of working script

```
using System;

public class Program
{

public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime[] dates = {
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,5),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,0,10), // 10 s USR 1

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,5,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,5,5),  // 05 s USR 2

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,1),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,0,10,2), // 02 s USR 3

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,1,0,0),  // 00 s USR 4

                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,2,0,0),
                                new DateTime(2014,01,01,2,0,20)  // 20 s USR 5
                            };


            int users = dates.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            int gapS = 20; // Gap between date in seconds
            double totalTimeGaps = 0;
            double totalTime = 0;

            for (int i = 0, n = i + 1; i < dates.Length - 1; i++, n++)
            {
                double range = (dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds;  
                totalTime += range;

                if (range > gapS)
                {
                    users++;
                    totalTimeGaps += range;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Users: " + users);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Time Avg. Session : " + (totalTime - totalTimeGaps)/users);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Time App." + (totalTime - totalTimeGaps));
        }

}
```

Comment: What does the comment "Does not count properly" mean?

Comment: User 1 spent 10 seconds, not 15.  User 3 spend 2 seconds, not 3.  User 4 spent 1 hour 20 seconds.  Are those mistakes of yours, or are you not actually calculating the interval of the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results I get are exactly as I'd expect when I run your program:

```
Total Users: 5
Total Time Avg. Session : 7.4
```

There are five users whose duration is 10s, 5s, 2s, 0s, 20s.

The total time is thus 37 seconds over 5 users which averages to 7.4s/user.

Your problem seems to be not in the code but in your own understanding of the data. You seem to have failed to note that what you record as user 4 is in fact two users and you are miscounting some of the timings (seemingly when there are three times involved).

Your code is correct according to the specs you gave us, you are just validating your code incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks all for your support, here a copy of the code refactored https://dotnetfiddle.net/hkLBT0

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using one `List<DateTime>` for every session-group:

```
List<List<DateTime>> sessions = new List<List<DateTime>> { new List<DateTime>() };
foreach(DateTime dt in dates)
{
    if(!sessions.Last().Any())
        sessions.Last().Add(dt);
    else
    {
        TimeSpan diff = dt - sessions.Last().Last();
        if (diff.TotalSeconds > 20)
            sessions.Add(new List<DateTime> { dt });
        else
            sessions.Last().Add(dt);
    }
}
```

You can use `List<double>` for every average:

```
List<double> secondsPerSession = new List<double>();
foreach (var session in sessions)
{
    if (session.Count == 1)
        secondsPerSession.Add(0);
    else
    {
        double average = session.Skip(1)
            .Average(d => (d - session[0]).TotalSeconds);
        secondsPerSession.Add(average);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sessions.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", 
        string.Join(",", sessions[i]), secondsPerSession[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your condition in you cycle. You count only the total gaps between two users and not the total time what a user has spent in your system. It should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0, n = i + 1; i < dates.Length - 1; i++, n++)
{
    totalTime += (dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds;
    if ((dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds > gapS)
    {
        users++;
        Console.WriteLine(totalTimeGaps);
    }
    else
    {
        totalTimeGaps += (dates[n] - dates[i]).TotalSeconds; // Does not count       properly
    }
}
```

Also if you want to get the average at the end of the cycle you should divide the total amount of time with the total number of users counter.